# How set value for TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce

How can one set the value for TinyMCE or reset its current value?

The form name is `form` and element which associated with TinyMCE is `editor`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the question. Could you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(....)`

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for any textarea, just specify id of textarea.

For example, id of textarea is country then

```
tinyMCE.get('country').setContent('AnyCountryName');
```